# Require Laravel query explanation

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Can anyone explain me what does `IF(transactions.retail_cost > 0,1,0)` means from the below query ?

```
$query = Distributors::selectRaw(
    "distributors.name,distributors.group_id,"
    . "distributors.pay,"
    . "SUM(IF(transactions.retail_cost > 0,1,0)) AS trans_number"
);
```

Comment: Check this helpful [link](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/control-flow-functions/if-function.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its counting the number of transactions.retail_cost that are greater than 0.

So to break it down,

SUM all the 1's from this following IF statement
IF transactions.retail_cost is greater than 0 then 1 else 0

effectively sums all the 1s produced from that statement producing a count

Comment: Then IF(transactions.retail_cost > 0) can solve the requirement but what does IF(transactions.retail_cost > 0,1,0) mean with 0,1,0

Comment: It seems understanding but can you be more clear. I am not sure about the answer.

Comment: its just sytactic suger to make it more readable. The reason it works without the 0,1,0 is that TRUE evaluates to 1 and False evaluates to 0

Comment: So u mean from SUM(IF(transactions.retail_cost > 0,1,0)), the query is gonna make sum of returned 1's  AS trans_number when ever the retail_cost is greater than 0 ?

Comment: yep. So effectively a count